# Gedit + Latex Plugin - Bibtex not working

Tags: latex, gedit

I writed an article in latex some time ago. Now that i use Ubuntu i work with Gedit + Latex plugin. I use bibtex and i found no problem running the work already done.

Now when i add a new entry to my bibtex file it doens't appear on pdf (like it wasn't there [?] ). The older references are correctly displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Ubuntu or gedit. Simply adding an entry to your `.bib` file is not sufficient. You will have to run bibtex again to display the new references (assuming you have cited them in the `.tex` file).

If you are using `latex` to compile to a pdf, follow these steps:

1. `latex filename`
2. `bibtex filename`
3. `latex filename`
4. `latex filename`
5. `dvipdf filename` (or you can do `dvips filename` followed by `ps2pdf filename`

If you are using `pdflatex`, then do these:

1. `pdflatex filename`
2. `bibtex filename`
3. `pdflatex filename`
4. `pdflatex filename`

Comment: Thks man ;) 

I thougth the gedit plugin should run the bibtex command too, but apparently not.